# Create dynamic triggers based on user selection from managed package

Tags: trigger, managed-package, generics

I have a requirement where I need to create two triggers inside a managed package. So, when the package is installed, the admin has a choice to either use the default objects available in the package or configure 2 different objects for further process. I have to create two triggers that will work on either case (either the admin chooses to go with default objects or admin chooses two of it's own SObjects). I want my trigger to work either way. How can I achieve this?